# How can I display the comment box for each container when the comment button is clicked?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a wrapper contained in a PHP while loop. Each time the loop runs, a new wrapper with another set of info from the database is added to our document. Each wrapper has a comment section where users can post comments. But I am hiding the comment boxes until the user clicks on the comment button(.btn-comment). But this displays all the comment boxes when I click on just one button. How can I solve this problem?

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('.comment-box').hide();
});
$('.btn-comment').on('click', function(e) {
$('.comment-box').show('slow');
});
```

```css
* {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
font-family: Arial;
}
.wrapper {
width: 100%;
}
.comment-box {
display: block !important;
width: 80%;
margin: 10px auto;
}
.btn-comment {
padding: 5px;
cursor: pointer;
}
textarea {
padding: 5px;
width: 75%;
border-radius: 5px;
vertical-align: middle;
}
.s_comment {
padding: 5px;
width: 20%;
border-radius: 5px;
vertical-align: middle;
background-color: lightblue;
border: 1px solid #303030;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- This is contained in a php while loop. Each time the loop runs, a new wrapper is created returning another set of data from the database -->
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div><!-- Publishes are fetched from the database and echo here --></div>
  <div class='btn btn-comment'>Comment</div>
  <div class='comment-box'>
  <textarea rows='1' placeholder='Write your comment'></textarea>
  <button class='s_comment'>Comment</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting at the button that was clicked, find its parent wrapper, which is the parent to the button and the box, and then find the box you want to show.

```
$(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.comment-box').show('slow');
```

Comment: Yeah. This is working really fine. I tried this yesterday.  I was distracted, I didn't use the find function. Thank you